# What's the use of & in Programming languages?

Tags: java, groovy

I have seen the use of `&` in many programming language and since I love groovy a lot I tried the following code to find the use of `&` :

```
​a = 1 ;
println a & 2​
```

I'm getting the output as `0`. When I change the values of `a` I get different answer's.

So any one can say whats the use of `&` in programming languages like Groovy in simple english, possibly with an simple example in any language?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction

Comment: The meaning of a symbol often varies by language, and that's one of the things that makes programming languages unique. It's not a good idea to ask such a general question as there may be (and in fact are) subtle differences in the use of this symbol in all the languages you list.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to say. Why is this tagged with 5 different languages?

Comment: Yeah, I'm considering removing some of them but I don't know which ones to remove...

Comment: Nevermind now. :P It's been edited.

Comment: Down vote removed as the original poster has removed tags for [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)), [Brainf***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) and all the other unrelated programming languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&` is usually either bitwise-and (on integer arguments) or non-short-circuiting logical and (on boolean arguments).

bitwise-and returns a series of bits (usually represented as an `int` type) that have only the bits in common set

```
18          == 10010
6           == 00110
18 & 6 == 2 == 00010
```

This seems to be what is happening in your Groovy code.  `1 & 2 == 0` since 1 and 2 share no bits in common.

Non-short-ciruiting logical and is similar to `&&` but

```
if (f() && g())   // g is only called if f returns false
if (f() &  g())   // g is called even when f returns false
```

In languages that allow operator overloading, libraries sometimes overloaded `&` to do set intersection, or element-wise bit-intersection.

Answer (score 4):

Searching "Groovy Operator" in Google, the first result yields: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators

> In general all operators [supported in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) are identical in Groovy.

Further in http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html:

> ```
> bitwise AND   &
> ```

Searching for "Bitwise AND" in Google, the first result is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

> #### AND
>
> A bitwise AND takes two binary representations of equal length and
>   performs the logical AND operation on each pair of corresponding bits.
>   For each pair, the result is 1 if the first bit is 1 AND the second
>   bit is 1; otherwise, the result is 0. For example:
>
> ```
>     0101 (decimal 5)
> AND 0011 (decimal 3)
>   = 0001 (decimal 1)
> ```

it takes less than 5 minute to work all that out.